# Table generated on PHP page not displaying as expected

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

So I have this table generating on a php page.

It generated fine for the most part except that the `$month` displayed from line 11 is put below the table headers instead of above them.

this only occurs on the first `$month`

the rest of them show up in the correct spot

You can see an example of what I mean here

[image]

Here is the code

```
<table id="coursesTable" class="table">
<?php
foreach ($courses as $month => $courseArr) {
    $previousDate = "";
    $count        = 1;
?>

    <?php
    if (!empty($courseArr)) {

        echo '<tr><td><h2>' . date("F Y", strtotime($month . "/" . date("y"))) . '</h2></td></tr>';

?>

         <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Course</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
       <th scope="col">Book/Register</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>



  <?php
    }
?>
 <tbody>

  <?php



    foreach ($courseArr as $course) {




        $date4 = isset($course->date4) ? ' & ' . date('jS g:ia', strtotime($course->date4)) . ' ' : '';


        if (isset($course->date4)) {
            $date3 = isset($course->date3) ? '<br> & ' . date('l F jS', strtotime($course->date3)) . ' ' : '';
        } else {
            $date3 = isset($course->date3) ? '<br> & ' . date('l F jS g:ia', strtotime($course->date3)) . ' ' : '';
        }


        $date2 = isset($course->date2) ? ' & ' . date('jS g:ia', strtotime($course->date2)) . ' ' : '';
        $date  = isset($course->date) ? date('l F jS', strtotime($course->date)) : date('l F jS g:ia', strtotime($course->date));




        echo '<tr ' . (($count % 2 == 1) ? 'class=""' : '') . ' >';

        echo '<td>' . $date . $date2 . $date3 . $date4 . '</td>';

        echo '<td>' . $course->location . '</td>';

        echo '<td><strong>' . $course->name . '</strong></td>';

        $price = $course->price;

        if ($price <= 0.00) {
            echo '<td><strong>COURSE IS FULL</strong></td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>' . $course->price . '</td>';


            echo '<td style=""><a href="http://lifestarttraining.com/index.php/cart?quantity[' . $course->id . ']=1"><img src="../../images/book_now.png"></a></td>';

        }


        $count += 1;
?>
       </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
   </tbody>
    <?php

}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: looking at the html sorce might help

Comment: If I were a browser, I'd also have to improvise if you're feeding me multiple `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in a single `<table>`, as well as a `<tr>` for your month header that's not even in a `<thead>` or `<tbody>`.

Comment: Why are you not making multiple tables with the date at the top?